# "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'"

Tags: python

Whenever I tried to run this code:

```
page = requests.get(URL, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
converted_price = price[0:7]


if (converted_price < '₹ 1,200'):
    send_mail()
print(converted_price)
print(title.strip())
if(converted_price > '₹ 1,400'):
    send_mail()
```

It gives me an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'` earlier this code was working fine.

Comment: UI might get changed. ID: `priceblock_ourprice` might be no longer available in new UI.

Comment: Either `soup.find(id="productTitle")` or `soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice")` returned `None`

Answer (score 4):

```
import requests



from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Camera-24-2MP-18-135mm-Essential-Including/dp/B081PMPPM1/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?dchild=1&keywords=Canon+EOS+80D&qid=1593325243&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEyU1M0M1JVTkY3WTBVJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNDQzMjI5Uk9DM08zQkM1RU9RJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTAyNjI0NjkzT0ZLUExSRkdJMDYmd2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9hdGYmYWN0aW9uPWNsaWNrUmVkaXJlY3QmZG9Ob3RMb2dDbGljaz10cnVl'

headers = { "user-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(url,headers= headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"lxml")

title = soup.find(id = "productTitle").get_text()

print(title)
```

i tried this and it worked

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

Either the `productTitle` id or the `priceblock_ourprice` id do not exist in the page you are querying. I would suggest you following two steps:
- Check the URL on your browser and look for that ids
- Check what you get in `page.content` because it is maybe not the same as what you see in the browser

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I assume you trying analyze Amazon products.
Elements `productTitle`  and `priceblock_ourprice` exist (I have checked).

You should check `page.content`. 
Maybe your `headers` are unacceptable for website.

Try:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.amazon.de/COMIFORT-PC-Tisch-Studie-Schreibtisch-Mehrfarbig/dp/B075R95B1S"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()

print(title)
print(price)
```

Result:

```
COMIFORT, Computerschreibtisch, Schreibtisch für das Arbeitszimmer, Schreibtisch, Maße: 90 x 50 x 77 cm                         
50,53 €
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check it might be the reason product it out of stock means price in not there in the site thats why its Nonetype. Try to select another product with visible price.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is 2.2 years late, but I'm going through this DevEd tutorial now -
and 'ourprice' is now 'id="priceblock_dealprice". But only runs once every 15 attempts.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It works once and then stops working. Amazon is blocking the request I think.

The ids are correct and it does not change if you use `lxml`, `html.parser`, or `html5lib`. Provided you `print(soup)` and look in the body, you will see a captcha prompt from amazon basically saying you have to prove you are not a robot. I don't know a way around that.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to run it consecutive days you will run into this error.  Amazon if blocking the request.  One trick to get it working again is to simply print the html after you get it before trying to parse.

```
response = requests.get(url=AMAZON_URI, headers={
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
})
response.raise_for_status()

data = response.text
# Adding this print will fix the issue for consecutive days.
print(data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
price_dollar = soup.find(name="span", class_="a-price-whole").getText()
price_cents = soup.find(name="span", class_="a-price-fraction").getText()
total_price = (float(f"{price_dollar}{price_cents}"))


print(total_price)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to print the total_price without printing the data and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33918595)